# C language Creating an instance and data type with Linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, types, linked-list

I'm studying C language with a book called Sams Teach Yourself. I understand the concept of linked lists, but cannot understand the technique. I'm going to write down how I understand this and have some questions along the way. Please let me know if I'm wrong or you know the answer to the questions. Here we go.

### SECTION 1

Preliminarily, I need to define the data structure and declare the head pointer to start a linked list like below.

```
struct person{
  char name[20];
  struct person *next;
};
struct person *new;
struct person *head;
head = NULL;
```

In here, a simple structure is defined. Its type or tag name is `person`. It has 1 element, an array called name, and 1 self-referencing pointer called next. After the definition of the structure, 2 pointers are declared. One of them is initialized to `NULL`, because it is a good practice when there's nothing to point.

### Section 1 Question

- Do I understand preliminaries of the linked list correctly in section 1?

### SECTION 2

The book explains that the procedure for adding a new element to the start of the list is 3-steps.

1. Create an instance of your structure, allocating memory space using
   malloc().
2. Set the next pointer of the new element to the current value of the head pointer. This will be NULL if the list is empty, or the address of the current first element otherwise.
3. Make the head pointer point to the new element.

```
    new = (person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    new->next = head;
    head = new
```

`new` is assigned with `malloc`, which I have a question about. The value`NULL` of`head` is assigned to the self-referencing pointer because it is the last pointer. Then the value of `new` is assigned to `head` the top pointer to point.

### Section 2 Qustions

- Where in this code is creating an instance? Isn't the format `struct tag instance` for creating an instance? Is `new` a instance? Isn't it a pointer declared in section 1?
- How does `sizeof(struct person)` work? `sizeof(char)` is 1 because `char` is 1-byte. How could `struct person` have a value because it is only a tag name?
- The book explains that `malloc()` is typecast so that its return value is the proper type - a pointer to the person data structure. I thought the data types in C were only `int, char, float` and variations of them. Is a pointer a data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In here, a simple structure is defined. Its type or tag name is `person`. It has 1 element, an array called name, and 1 self-referencing pointer called next. After the definition of the structure, 2 pointers are declared. One of them is initialized to `NULL`, because it is a good practice when there's nothing to point.

All correct, but to be 100% precise there is no "self-referencing pointer", it's just a pointer field which points to a structure of the same type, it could point to *any other* structure of that type.

> Where in this code is creating an instance? Isn't the format struct tag instance for creating an instance? Is new a instance? Isn't it a pointer declared in section 1?

"Creating an instance" is bad wording. There is no such thing as "instancing" in C. In C, memory can be allocated in two main ways: automatically (via a variable declaration) or dynamically (via an explicit call to `malloc()` or similar functions).

Automatic allocation of variables happens on the stack and (as the word implies) is automatic: you do not need to worry about explicitly reserving space for the variable, the compiler does it for you, and it also frees up that space when the variable gets out of scope. Dynamic allocation is *manually* performed by the user, and thus also needs manual cleanup using `free()` to free the allocated space once it is not needed anymore.

In this case since you declared a *pointer* `struct person *new` you have automatically allocated space for *the pointer itself*, but you still need to allocate space for the `struct` if you want that pointer to point to something valid.

> How does `sizeof(struct person)` work?

Every type has a known fixed size (almost, there are exceptions). A structure composed of multiple basic types has a size that is *at least* the sum of the sizes of its fields. Your `struct person` is a new type defined by you, which has itself a size, it's not just a "tag name". Every time you create a variable of type `struct person`, your program needs to allocate `sizeof(struct person)` bytes for it. In particular:

```
sizeof(struct person) >= 20 * sizeof(char) + sizeof(struct person *);
//                            ^^^ always 1   ^^^ usually 4 (on a 32bit system) or 8 (on a 64bit system)
```

> The book explains that `malloc()` is typecast so that its return value is the proper type - a pointer to the person data structure.

The book is *wrong*. You do **not** need to cast the result of `malloc()`. In C, there's a special type: `void`: it means "no type". The associated pointer type, `void *`, means "a pointer to any type", and is what `malloc()` returns.

A pointer of type `void *` is guaranteed to be *always* castable to any other pointer type, and the conversion from/to `void *` to/from any other pointer type happens automatically without the need of an explicit cast. [See also here for a good explanation](http://%20Also,%20as%20good%20practice,%20[don't%20cast%20the%20return%20value%20of%20%60malloc()%60][1].) of why casting the return value of `malloc()` is a bad idea.

> I thought the data type in C is only `int, char, float & variation of them`. Is a pointer a data type?

Oh no, it's not only those. You just defined a new data type yourself (`struct person`). I'm surprised your book did not define what a data type is before diving into higher level stuff like linked lists and dynamic memory allocation. A pointer is indeed another basic data type in C, since you can take the address of any variable of any type, there exist as many pointer data types as non-pointer data types: `int *`, `char *`, `float *`, ecc. In fact, `struct person *` is a pointer data type, identifying a pointer to a variable of type `struct person`.